# how do i create this pine script strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

i wanted to create a pine script strategy which place a buy order if the first 30 minute candle of current session was a positive/green one and vice versa. I want to place stop loss at the high of the said 30 minute candle in case of short order and low of the said 30 minute candle in case of long order. then I want to trail the stop loss to high of the next red candle whenever it comes in case of short order ( even if there are green candles in between the first candle and the red candle unless it is breaking the high of the former) and complete opposite in case of long order. I hope I was able to explain my query.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Close of first bar of a day", overlay=true)

fromMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='From Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
fromDay = input.int(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
fromYear = input.int(defval=2023, title='From Year', minval=1970)
thruMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='Thru Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
thruDay = input.int(defval=1, title='Thru Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
thruYear = input.int(defval=2023, title='Thru Year', minval=1970)
start = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)
end = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 23, 59)
isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1] 


var firstBarHighValue = high
var firstBarLowValue = low
var firstBarCloseValue = close
var firstBarOpenValue =open
var trailingsl = 0.0
dh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high)

if isNewDay
    firstBarLowValue := low
    firstBarHighValue := high
    firstBarCloseValue := close
    firstBarOpenValue := open
if firstBarOpenValue > firstBarCloseValue and time >= start and time < end
    trailingsl := firstBarHighValue
    strategy.entry("Enter Short",strategy.short,qty= 1)
    if open > close
        trailingsl := high
        strategy.exit("ExitingfromShort",from_entry = "Enter Short",qty = 1,trail_price = trailingsl,trail_offset = 10)



plot(firstBarHighValue)
plot(firstBarLowValue)
```

Comment: What's your question? Try to include something with a question mark.

Comment: Question is in the title. I tried to create but it doesn't work accordingly.

Comment: Are you getting errors? What's not working as expected?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.